# Matlab: convert array of number to array of strings

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, type-conversion

How can I convert `[12 25 34 466 55]` to an array of strings `['12' '25' '34' '466' '55']`? The conversion functions I know convert that array to one string representing the entire array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An array of strings has to be a cell array.  That said:

```
s = [12 25 34 466 55]
strtrim(cellstr(num2str(s'))')
```

Comment: A better way than what I wrote above.

Comment: This is over twice as fast than both arrayfun and cellfun. +1

Answer (score 13):

Now after MATLAB 2016b, you can simply use

```
s = [12 25 34 466 55]; 
string(s)
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `arrayfun` together with `num2str` would work:

```
>> A = [12 25 34 466 55]
A =
   12    25    34   466    55

>> arrayfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false)
ans = 
    '12'    '25'    '34'    '466'    '55'
```

Comment: why not `arrayfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false)`? Same concept, same output, but you avoid the "from-cell" and "to-cell" conversions.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, ['12' '25' '34' '466' '55'] is the same as a single string containing those numbers. That is to say:

```
['12' '25' '34' '466' '55']

ans =

12253446655
```

I need more context here for what you are trying to accomplish, but assuming you want to still be able to access each individual number as a string, a cell array is probably the best approach you can take:

```
A = [1 2 3]
num2cell(num2str(A))
```

(Of course, you'd still have to remove the stray spaces from the ans)

Comment: Even if you remove the stray spaces, you end up with a cell array of strings that contains each digit separately. Swap the order of `num2cell` and `num2str` instead. `cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(s),'UniformOutput',false)` gets the job done nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from R2016b there is also the compose function:

```
>> A = [12 25 34 466 55]

A =

    12    25    34   466    55

>> compose("%d", A)

ans = 

  1×5 string array

    "12"    "25"    "34"    "466"    "55"'''
```